# RequireJs - feeding values from one dependency as parameter for another dependency

Tags: requirejs, js-amd

We have wrapped the Google Maps API as an asynchronous module in RequireJs.

```
define(['async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=APIKEY&sensor=true'],

function(){
    var maps = window.google.maps;

    return maps;
});
```

Now we wish to extract out the API key into a config.js file to store configuration settings for different environments. But there is no way this can work (since the variable name hasn't been defined yet)

```
define([config,
'async!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key' + config.APIKEY + '&sensor=true'],
```

I tried some double nesting of define() and require() to no avail. How would one write the dependency chain to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: I need this too! Any progress?

Comment: So you're looking for something like define([config], function(config) { require([GOOGLEMAPS + config.APIKEY], function() {}); });? Do you have a more detailed code sample?

Comment: Hey Chris, the above example is the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of right now would include a callback. Something like:

```
define([], function() {
    var exports = {};

    exports.Maps = function (maps) {
        this.hello = function () {
            console.log(maps);
        };
    };

    exports.Factory = function (apiKey) {
        this.manufacture = function (loadedCallback) {
            require(['http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=' + apiKey + '&sensor=true'], function () {
                loadedCallback(new exports.Maps(window.google.maps));
            });
        };
    };

    return exports;
});
```

Then to use it you would do:

```
require(["foo"], function (Foo) {

    var apiKey = "blablabla",
        factory = new Foo.Factory(apiKey);
    factory.manufacture(function (Maps) {
        Maps.hello();
    });

});
```